# Puts Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I have this hash, and want to print it:

```
{:date=>#<Date: 2013-03-29 ((2456381j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Karfreitag", :regions=>[:de]}
{:date=>#<Date: 2013-04-01 ((2456384j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Ostermontag", :regions=>[:de]}
{:date=>#<Date: 2013-05-01 ((2456414j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :name=>"Tag der Arbeit", :regions=>[:de]}
```

I tried it with:

```
def print_holiday(a)        
  a.each do |date|
    puts date["name"] + " " + date["date"]
  end                   
end
```

But all I get are some empty lines. Got any ideas?

I'm using the holidays gem.

Answer (score 10):

A string is not a symbol. Keys in your hash are symbols, but you're trying to access values through strings.

Try this:

```
puts date[:name] + " " + date[:date]
```

[The Difference Between Ruby Symbols and Strings](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)

Comment: The question is tagged with `ruby-on-rails`, where string keys and symbol keys can often be used interchangeably (`HashWithIndifferentAccess`).

Comment: @Stefan: well, obviously this is not the case here. Also, the question has nothing to do with rails.

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to point out that this can be quite confusing and it might not be that obvious, that *"a string is not a symbol"*.